# How to find if image exists or not - parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have successfully retrieved the image (lets say user profile pic) from parse, and i'm displaying it in the ios app. But if there is no image in the file column, then i want to display default image which is stored in the locally (not in parse), not successful.

My simple question is, how to check if there is image or not ? Below is the simple code;

```
PFFile *userImage = [object objectForKey:@"profilePic"]; __block UIImage *userProfilePic =[[UIImage alloc]init];

[userImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //this block will execute only if there is image
        if(data) {
            userProfilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            userPic.image=userProfilePic;
        }

        //this block is not at all executing. This block should execute when user doesn't have their profile uploaded
        if(!data) {
            UIImage *userProfileDefaultPic = [[UIImage alloc]init];
            userProfileDefaultPic=[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultprofile.png"];
            userPic.image=userProfileDefaultPic;
        }
    }
}];
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Pradeep

Comment: Try logging "userPic.image" and post result.

Comment: Add logs for both the instances... The image exists and the image does not exists.

Comment: Thanks Jeet. I didn't try this, i'll try

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat , i'm getting error while trying to log (userPic.image). I have done in some other way - uploading default image while user registration. Thanks for trying to help me. I need to check Rahmi's updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last found the solution !

`(!data)` will not execute , instead we need to check if the PFFile and the UIImage to store PFFile has image or not, like below;

```
PFFile *userImage = [object objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
               __block UIImage *userProfilePic =[[UIImage alloc]init];
if(userImage && ![userProfilePic isEqual:[NSNull null]]) //This is important to check if the file if image is there or not and if not, then display default pic in else part

{
            [userImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if(!error)
                {

                        userProfilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        userPic.image=userProfilePic;

                }
                 }];
            }
            else
            {
                userProfilePic =[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultprofilepic.png"];
                userPic.image=userProfilePic;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already does that. You just need to set your image on the main thread and not background thread.

```
if(!data) { [dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *userProfileDefaultPic = [[UIImage alloc]init];
        userProfileDefaultPic=[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultprofile.png"];
        userPic.image=userProfileDefaultPic;
}}];
```

Comment: Thanks Rahim. But the default image is not displaying, i tried in different ways, no success

Comment: You need to update image in main thread.     [dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //update And set image here//
}];


See edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I tried both with sysc and async